# How to activate command line? Only one line shown after I opened terminal

Tags: macos, authentication, command-line, terminal

[image]

There is only the first line showing 'last login' here. Whatever I typed in the command line and pressed 'Enter', it doesn't execute...
I accidentally entered this mode and forget how to get back to the 'users-MacBook-Pro:~ username$' mode
BTW, my mac system is 10.10.5

Comment: control + shift + \  just solved the problem... However, it is annoying to keep doing it, so any suggestion to get rid of it? I remember originally the terminal wasn't like this...

Answer (score 0):

Usually to exit any terminal based application control-c works to return to bash but you can also use control z to exit the current shell, but it doesn't terminate the program